# Python2.7 (numpy) Keeping shape of array when appending a 3-d numpy array to an empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create an empty numpy array, and save all the images that I get from my device. The images come in as numpy array of shape (240,320,3). Creating an empty array to store these images seems like the correct thing to do. When I try to append however, I get this error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Code as follows:

```
    import numpy as np

    # will be appending many images of size (240,320,3)
    images = np.empty((0,240,320,3),dtype='uint8')

    # filler image to append
    image = np.ones((240,320,3),dtype='uint8') * 255

    images = np.append(images,image,axis=0)
```

I need to append many images to this array, so after `100` appends, the shape of the images array should be of shape `(100,240,320,3)` if done correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `images` array has four dimensions, so you must [`append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) a four dimensional item to it.  To do so, simply add a new axis to `image` like so:

```
images = np.append(images,image[np.newaxis, ...], axis=0)
```

In a sense, when passing an axis `numpy.append` is more akin to `list.extend` than `list.append`.

Comment: Of course, it'd make a lot more sense to stick these arrays in a list as they come and then build the combined array at the end, since repeatedly appending to an array is highly inefficient.

Comment: It is more like `alist = alist + [image]`

Answer (score 4):

Better than `np.append` is:

```
images = np.empty((100,240,320,3),dtype='uint8')
for i in range(100):
    image = ....
    images[i,...] = image
```

or

```
alist = []
for i in range(100):
     image = ....
     alist.append(image)
images = np.array(alist)
# or images = np.stack(alist, axis=0) for more control
```

`np.append` is just a cover for `np.concatenate`.  So it makes a new array each time through the loop.  By the time you add the 100th image, you have copied the first one 100 times!.  The other disadvantage with `np.append` is that you have to adjust the dimensions of `image`, a frequent source of error.  The other frequent error is getting that initial 'empty' array shape wrong.